# wait-then-hibernate on laptop lid closing

Tags: systemd, hibernate

I have a problem with suspend-then-hibernate as a lid closing action.

So, instead of suspending, I want my system to turn off and lock the screen and wait 10 minutes (but not suspend) once the lid is closed and then, if the lid remains closed, to hibernate.

Is it possible to do this using systemd?

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1072504/195571